# How to iterate over a dictionary in Python to move in different directions

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a text based game for my homework. I have been able to everything except move between rooms using the directions: North, South, East and West. I have not worked with dictionaries much at all and I am struggling. I do not understand how to do this especially in the bedroom with 2 different directions.
Directions: The game should prompt the player to enter commands to move between rooms
#The dictionary links a room to other rooms.

```
rooms = {
        'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
        'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is basically an answer to the OP's comment with reference to @John Gordon's Answer

In the question, rooms is a 2D dictionary (dictionary inside a dictionary). When we use `rooms[location]`, for example `rooms['Bedroom']`, it picks up the corresponding dictionary of moves from the key 'Bedroom' i.e. `{'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'}`, similarly if we use `rooms[location][move]`, it picks up the **value of the move from the dictionary that was returned**. So if I use `rooms['Bedroom']['North']` it will return 'Great Hall'.

I hope this solved your query

Answer (score 0):

Keep the name of the current room in a variable.

Ask the user where they would like to move.

If the current room allows movement in that direction, update the current room variable to the new room.

```
location = 'Great Hall'

print(f'You are currently in {location}.')
move = input('Enter a direction to move: ')
if move in rooms[location]:
    location = rooms[location][move]
    # location is now e.g. 'Bedroom'
else:
    print('You cannot go that way.')
```

Comment: so the [] indicates that part of the dictionary? The index and keys?

Comment: @John Gordon Add a brief bit of explanatory text outside of the code block and this will be the perfect answer, in my humble opinion. May the Source serve you well.